# Twitter and Zurb Foundation on same website, would they conflict?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, web, frameworks, zurb-foundation

I'm a startup web designer and I'm getting familiar with frameworks. I wanted to know can I use both Twitter Bootstrap and Zurb Foundation in a webpage? Would they conflict and cause problems with each other?

Answer (score 1):

Without editing any CSS, you would have conflicts using both Bootstrap and Foundation on the same webpage. Both frameworks have default conventions for CSS (body, headers, etc.) which would conflict.

If you want to quickly wireframe a website, I would recommend using one or the other. If you feel as though you are missing out on a particular feature, you could then port that feature over to work with your chosen framework.